# Lorentz's Amsterdam Proceedings 12:986 (1904) paper?

Tags: specific-reference, history

I am looking for this paper by H. A. Lorentz:

> *Amsterdam Proceedings* **12** (1904) 986. (See also *Arch. Neér. Sciences Exactes et Naturelles* **25** (1882) 363.)

I have also seen it cited using the journal abbreviation "Verl.":

> Verl. 1̲2̲, 986 (1904).

What paper / journal is this?

thanks

Comment: 'Verl.' is probably short for 'Verlag', which is German for 'publisher'. So, I guess _that_ is a mistake in that particular citation.

Comment: I also think 'Neér.' should be 'Néer.' as it probably stands for the French 'Néerlandais(e(s))' (which means 'Dutch'). (And, I'm not sure, but _I_ would abbreviate that as 'Néerl.')

Comment: [Related meta discussion](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4490).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The title of the paper is: *"Electromagnetic phenomena in a system moving with any velocity smaller than that of light"*

It can be found in full here: http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_phenomena. Scans of the original are available, at least for the moment, [here (pdf)](http://www.dwc.knaw.nl/DL/publications/PU00014148.pdf) and [here (png's)](http://ether-wind.narod.ru/Lorentz_1904/). As wikisource notes the work is in the public domain in most territories.

The full citation is listed as:

> H. A. Lorentz: Amsterdam Proceedings 12 (1904) 986; Ne´er Sciences Exactes et Naturelles 25 (1882) 363; Proc. Acad.
>   Science Amsterdam 6 (1904) 809

It is also available as pp. 172-197 of (paywalled)

> [Collected Papers. Volume V.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-94-015-3445-1_5) H. A. Lorentz. (Springer, Netherlands, 1937).

Comment: I thought that was *Amst. Proc.* **6**:809 (1904).

Comment: no, it's Amst. Proc. **12**. But it's Proc. Acad. Science Amst. **6**

Comment: Ah, thanks! So it was published in multiple journals?

Comment: @Geremia Yes, it was